# Command line parameters in Java

Tags: java, bash, command-line-arguments, javac

I am working on a project in Java where I have to let the user to put the command line arguments something similar as we do in UNIX to perform certain functionalities.

e.g If my program name is foo.java:

```
//So when I compile it 
javac foo.java    <Enter>
//Run it
java foo          <Enter>
//Input Argument
list              <Enter>
 <List of all the users>
```

I know that we can pass the command line arguments with java eg java foo list, but if I don't have to pass the Command line argument and have to pass the arguments as a Unix shell command. Any example would help!!

Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what your question is.

Comment: are you confusing command line arguments with user input during the run of your program?

Comment: by **list <enter>** do you mean execution **java foo list** and outputting the list?

Comment: I think the question is how to read standard input from a pipe in Java.

Comment: RAZ_Muh_Taz .. I think you got me. I am looking for how to pass the user inputs from the command line during the run of the program.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusing question..... I was not getting the right word to put in .
So the question is when I run my java program , it should wait for the user input from the command line and then execute the functionalities coded in the program as per input from the user.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to be able to give input through a pipe, like

```
echo arg1 arg2 arg3 | java foo
```

To do this, your program must read standard input. This is typically accomplished with the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.

Here's a brief example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = console.nextLine();
    System.out.println(input);
  }
}
```

Invoking with `java ScannerTest` will wait until the user inputs a line and hits return. Invoking with `echo "Hello, world!" | java ScannerTest` completes essentially immediately, because instead of using the keyboard as standard input, Java considers the pipe as standard input.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to create a command line java application which runs similarly like linux programs.

I think a nice option is to use https://argparse4j.github.io/ library. You can have a look in their samples since its quite intuitive:

```
    ArgumentParser parser = ArgumentParsers.newArgumentParser("Checksum")
                    .defaultHelp(true)
                    .description("Calculate checksum of given files.");
            parser.addArgument("-t", "--type")
                    .choices("SHA-256", "SHA-512", "SHA1").setDefault("SHA-256")
                    .help("Specify hash function to use");
            parser.addArgument("file").nargs("*")
                    .help("File to calculate checksum");
Namespace ns = null;
        try {
            ns = parser.parseArgs(args);
        } catch (ArgumentParserException e) {
            parser.handleError(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

Then you can call like:
$ java Checksum -h